# Unable to Locate Element with Selenium Python despite xPath

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I can't locate element on website and insert numerical value inside using Selenium on Firefox with Python.

1. I am using firefox add-in to get the xPath for the input field, I receive:

   /html/body/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46UHr.png)/section/div/div/div/div/form/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46UHr.png)/div/div[4]/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rA58h.png)/div/div/div/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46UHr.png)/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46UHr.png)/table/tbody/tr[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46UHr.png)/td[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpY16.png)/div/input

however with Python code objDriver.find_element_by_xpath("...") - I receive "Unable to locate element:" -> like xpath is wrong

2. If I use it on the let's say border of the input field, I get following xPath:

   /html/body/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46UHr.png)/section/div/div/div/div/form/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46UHr.png)/div/div[4]/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rA58h.png)/div/div/div/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46UHr.png)/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46UHr.png)/table/tbody/tr[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46UHr.png)/td[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpY16.png)

This element I can allocate using objDriver.find_element_by_xpath("...") but it is not input field, so I can't insert value

3. If I click "Inspect" in Firefox, I get:

CSS Path:

```
html body div.main-content section.section div.block-one_col_1 div.container-fluid.wrapper div.row div.col-12 form#id_form-process.form-horizontal.formfactory div.row div.col-md div#fieldgroup_variants.fieldset div#fieldgroup_variants__fields.fieldset__content div.form-group.row.formfield_variantsCalculator.fieldpk_2533.mb-0.is-valid div.col-md-6.col-12 div.d-flex.flex-row div.w-100 div.table-scroll table.table.table--step tbody#tableContent.table tr.table-row.table-row--count td div.form-group.group1 input.form-control.variant-value.variant1.touched
```

xPath:

```
/html/body/div/section/div/div/div/div/form/div[1]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/div/input
```

HTML part I am interested in:

```
<td data-risk="6.1"><div class="form-group group1" data-excluded="false" data-risk="6.1"><input name="1" class="form-control variant-value variant1 touched" data-editable="true" data-risk="6.1" data-visible-sum="true" data-dynamic="false"></div></td>
```

Do you have any idea how can I locate the field I need? 
General view of Input field:

[image: General view on input field]

When getting xPath of the border:

[image: selection xPath of border]

When getting xPath of the Input field:

[image: Sole Input field, xPath]

Comment: I'd target the name... something like //input[contains(@name, "1")]... or name="1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try with the below `xpath` with `Explicit waits`  :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name= '1' and contains(@class, 'variant-value')]"))).send_keys('10000')
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: I copied whole code, unfortunately got response: ```- Error type: Message: Unable to locate element: //input[@class="form-control variant-value variant1 touched"][@id="1"]```

Comment: Can I have a URL for better understanding ?

Comment: It is closed system to which I cannot provide access.

Is there anything I can provide?

Comment: yes can you print this `print(driver.page_source)` and share the output

Comment: the xpath explanation is basically, we are targeting the input tag using `//input` and then we are trying to filter with the name attribute and class attributes, and we are using contains to look for specific text in class.  for this `it turned out that element on the website is correctly identified. Could you please explain,` - I would have to see the HTML structure at least to have an opinion.

Comment: As I understand after few tests, it seems that I was trying to find those elements on the website "too fast"

But at the same time, I'm pretty sure I tried using python ```time.sleep(10)```

Is it not the same? What is the difference?

Comment: You can minimize the use of sleep() method, since it's worst kind of a explicit wait. you can try to write web elements like above, which is a dynamic explicit waits.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `xPath = //input[@class="form-control variant-value variant1 touched"][@id="1"]`

Comment: Unofrtunately I got message
```- Error type: Message: Unable to locate element: //input[@class="form-control variant-value variant1 touched"][@id="1"]```
<br>
I Inserted it as
```fldField1= objDriver.find_element_by_xpath("""//input[@class="form-control variant-value variant1 touched"][@id="1"]""")```